# Surefire - TestNG : avoiding "old" directory creation

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

I'm using Surefire 2.16 and TestNG 6.8.5. The configuration in my pom.xml is really simple : no configuration (so Surefire must find out by itself the tests classes).

But I have 500 unit tests in this project and the generation of the "old" directory content is **very very slow** (it creates a sub-directory for each class/suite). The tests execution only takes 15 seconds, but with the old directory it raises to more than 800 seconds.

So I would like avoid this "old" directory (but keep the other generated files). I tried the parameter use usedefaultlisteners=false, but I loose all the reports.

Someone to tell me how I can do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Surefire docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) listeners may be added by setting the listener property as a CSV list of Class names.

You can understand what the default listeners are by looking at the [TestNG source](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java). Method is initializeDefaultListeners. Pick just the listeners that you need and add them yourself.